# Parse linux "top" in PHP?

Tags: php, linux, centos, monitoring, cpu-usage

I'm working on a monitoring tool in PHP. It should display the % cpu usage of a single process by PID . Keep in mind that I can't use ps because it takes the total usage and divides it by the time the process has been running. So that's the average usage. I need the usage in the moment the php file is ran.

Here's what I'm trying, it seems to be close to what I need in the terminal but php won't print anything.

```
$cmd = "top -n 1 -p 30100";
echo exec($cmd);
```

Is there maybe another better way of doing this? I can install utilities if they provide the functionality I need.

TL;DR I need the %cpu of a process by PID, as simple as possible to avoid parsing

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But could I somehow create a script that runs for one second, for example? And checks the usage in that second? None of the processes I'll monitor will ever be idle. How does top work? Does it run on a set interval and then print the result?

Comment: Have a look at /process/$pid/stat to get the amount of time a process has been running in various states. You'll need to poll each value more than once / over a period of time to get an accurate measure.

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet of how I would do that? I'm not that experienced. Here's how I imagine doing it, maybe a 10 cycle for() with a 100ms sleep, then calculate based on the ten values? Would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
top -n1 -p 30100 |grep -e 30100 | awk '{print $10}'
```

Comment: works like a charm , except I had to replace $10 with $9(it was outputting the %mem)

Answer (score 1):

Know that there is no such thing as instantaneous CPU usage %. It's like FPS in games: it only makes sense if you're asking about a particular time interval. At any particular moment the CPU usage of a process is simply "yes" or "no". There's no percentage.

> Could I somehow create a script that runs for one second, for example? And checks the usage in that second?

Absolutely. If you want to do it yourself, you can parse `/proc/<pid>/stat` and pull out the `utime` and `stime` fields -- the 14th and 15th integers, respectively. Wait one second, say, and then see how much those fields have changed.

See `man proc` for a full description of the fields in this file.

The man page says that the units are clock ticks, where the number of ticks per second is variable (the C function `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` gives you the number). In my (admittedly limited) experience the units are simply 1/100ths of a second. Meaning divide these numbers by 100 to get the number of seconds.

> Could you please provide a snippet of how I would do that? I'm not that experienced. Here's how I imagine doing it, maybe a 10 cycle for() with a 100ms sleep, then calculate based on the ten values?

There's no need to take more than two samples.

Comment: can this be done in PHP only? I found plenty of c snips, even bash scripts, but I have no idea where to start from or if I can even use them.

Comment: To be honest, this is overkill. I'm sure there's a way to get `top` to work for you. Or if your system has `sar`, try that. `sar` is much better at this sort of thing.

Comment: It doesn't , but I just installed it. I'm not sure how I can use sar tho. Meanwhile, If I could get the top to work, that would be great